# SQL - Percentage count

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table called **URP_PROJECT**, a column named **ts_title**. There are different record data under column **ts_title**. How to calculate the each record under **ts_title** as percentage? **Percentage** column is added according to the SQL query below.

I start with:

SELECT ts_title

COUNT (ts_title) AS Percentage

Help me continue it, Thank you

Comment: What database are you using MS SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle?

Comment: SSRS - SQL Server Reporting Service

Comment: What are the rest of the columns.  Is ts_title a varchar or an int?

Comment: I am confused.  count(ts_title) will count the number of rows where ts_title is not null.

Comment: Let me give u a good example:

under column Fruits, there are list of fruits name, even have repeated fruit name. I just want to calculate the percentage of each fruits.

Comment: I am not sure whether my above code part is correct or not. Do help tq

Answer (score 1):

this may give you what you are looking for

```
  select ts_title, 
         count(1) * 100.0 / (select count(1) from upr_project)
 from upr_project
group by ts_title
```

Multiplying times 100.0 converts it to a float for more accurate percentages.

Comment: Thanks! Converting to a float helped by percentages add to 100.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution is to use the window functions:

```
select ts_title,
       100.0 * (up.cnt*1.0 / (sum(up.cnt) over (partition by 1)))
from 
(
  select ts_title, count(*) as cnt
  from upr_project
  group by ts_title
) up
```

Comment: This solution also works when you have a "total" row using GROUPING SETS, ROLLUP or CUBE. You just multiply up.cnt by 2.0 instead of 1.0 to account for the extra volume of the "total" row.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT ts_title,
(count(ts_title) * 100 / (SELECT count(*) FROM URP_PROJECT)) as percentage 
FROM URP_PROJECT Group BY ts_title
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I guess you are looking for the percentage of the ts_title record over the entire table. If that is the case this would help you

```
DECLARE @ActualCount INT

select @ActualCount = COUNT(*) from urp_project


select ts_title
  ,(Count(ts_title)/ @ActualCount )* 100 AS Percentage       
from urp_project
group by ts_title;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, perhaps:

```
SELECT
  ts_title,
  COUNT(*) * 100.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER () AS percentage
FROM URP_PROJECT
GROUP BY ts_title
```

Useful reading:

- [OVER Clause (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)